# Manage Project in groupproject in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I have a projectgroup delphi wtih 5 projects How can I call any Project in a projectgroup and  what can i do to conncet this project with one menu project

delphi 10.1

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly and I don't have D10.1. But in D7 and XE6 you just double-click the project in the project manager treeview. It becomes the active project and marked in bold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily switch currently active project in the project group by double-clicking on its main node within the `Project Manager` window.

You can also select the project that you want to become active by selecting it in the project group and then clicking on `Activate selected Project` button within the `Project Manager` window.

[image: Activate Selected project Button]

If you click the downward arrow near the above mentioned button you even get a dropdown menu with all existing projects in your currently opened project group.

Comment: i'm not shur that u understend me ... my problem : 1- how can i do to call any project from other  2- how can i do to share datamodule betwin this project (they use the same database) thnk.s

Comment: OK I see. You want to share your DataModule between multiple applications. I'm afraid there is no simple answer to that. Why? Becouse it largely depends on what you mean by share. If you want to simply avoid designing your DataModule for each of your application (reuse some of your code) then you could move all the necessary code and components of this DataModule into separate package and design your applications to use this package for creating your DataModule. ...

Comment: ... But if you want to be able to share your data between multiple of your applications and see changes made in one of the applications instantly reflected in others. Well this becomes much more complicated as you would probably have to move your DataModule into separate application and make proper mechanism which will allow all other application to communicate with your DataModule application.